# Convert DateTime Format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert this datetime format from a webservice? The datetime value is:  "timestamp": "2014-04-18T14:45:00+02:00"
I wan't to convert it to: `dd.mm.YYYY hh.mm.ss`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK"` format with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "2014-04-18T14:45:00+02:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Take a look at [The `"K"` Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier)

Then you can get string representation of your `DateTime` with [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. `DateTime` has no inherent format, it has just a value. You can get string representation for formatting.

```
date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//18.04.2014 03.45.00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/60Y1U0)</kbd>.

Remember, `mm` is for minutes, `MM` for months. And `hh` is for *12-hour clock* which is `01` to `12`. But `HH` is *24-hour clock* which is `00` to `23`.

That's why you can't parse `14` with `hh` specifier. I assume your real representation format is `dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss`

**EDIT**: After your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155754/convert-datetime-format-in-c-sharp/23155806#comment35411319_23155806), you can use `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format like;

```
string s = "04/18/2014 14:45:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date); // 18/04/2014 14:45:00
```

Comment: i tried this but get an error from the debugger: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: if i debug the string variable s, ther stands: test = "04/18/2014 14:45:00"

Comment: @user2025830 But your string formats does not match. Anyway, updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)` or `DateTime.TryParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, out DateTime`).

- [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With a regex you can do the following:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\w{1}(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\+\d{2}:\d{2}", "$3.$2.$1 $4.$5.$6", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

> //18.04.2014 14.45.00

Comment: @SonerGönül I agree, there are libraries for that but it's also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "2014-04-18T14:45:00+02:00";
var results = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```